# Python hangman without lists

Tags: python, list, python-3.6

I need a simple Python Hangman program without using Lists - It is just one word
HAPPY  - this program works - BUT...
This is what I did, with Lists - but teacher said Lists are not allowed
We do not have to draw hangman - we just prompt for the letters - print the "-" for each letter to show length of word.

```
def main():
secretword = "HAPPY"
displayword=[]
displayword.extend(secretword)

for I in range (len(displayword)):
  displayword[I]="_"
print ('current word

')
print (' '.join(displayword))

count = 0
while count < len(secretword):
  guess = input('Please guess a etter: ')

  for I in range(len(secretword)):
   if secretword[I] == guess:
       displayword[I] = guess
       countr - count + 1

   print (' '.join(displayword))

print (congratulations you guess the word')

main()
```

If you don't like the code - that's fine. This is how our teacher is requiring us to do this. I can see it is not like others do it. I only left out the comments - that are also required on every line of code

Comment: You are asking for someone to refactor your entire program for you. Questions like these are too broad and vague. Try narrowing down your issues to bite-sized questions.

Comment: There are over [700 questions about Hangman in python](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=hangman+%5Bpython%5D) on this site. Have you tried reading some of them?

Comment: yes - I have read 30-40 and they all contain LISTS

Answer (score 0):

One solution to your problem would be to use two strings, `secretword`, which is the word you're looking for and `displayword` which is what the user sees so far, the combination of letters and `-`. Every time you enter a letter, the program checks if the `secretword` contains that letter and if it does, it updates the character of the specific index in `displayword`:

```
def main():
    secretword = "HAPPY"
    length = len(secretword)
    displayword = '-' * length
    count = 0

    while count < length:
        guess = input("Please guess a letter: ")
        for i in range(length):
            if secretword[i] == guess:
                displayword[i] = guess
                count += 1
    print(displayword)
    print("Congratulations, you guessed the word.")

main()
```